# FFMPEG - make a stable & zero-padded frame counter

Tags: ffmpeg

I use FFMPEG to print a frame counter on my videos, but I have two issues:

[image: demo GIF]

1. The text stutters
2. I'd like to have the possibility to have the number zero-padded (I.E. write `001` `002` `003` instead of `1` `2` `3`).

Code:

```sh
@echo off
:again

cd /D %~p1

ffmpeg ^
    -i "%~nx1" ^
    -vf "drawtext=fontfile=arialbd.ttf: text='Frame \: %%{n}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=white: fontsize=40: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.4: boxborderw=8" ^
    -c:a copy ^
    "%~p1%~n1_framenumbered.mov"
if NOT ["%errorlevel%"]==["0"] goto:error
echo [92m%~n1 Done![0m

shift
if "%~1" == "" goto:end
goto:again

:error

echo [93mThere was an error. Please check your input file or report an issue on github.com/L0Lock/FFmpeg-bat-collection/issues.[0m
pause
exit 0

:end

cls
echo [92mEncoding succesful. This window will close after 10 seconds.[0m
timeout /t 10
```

#### Solutions:

- use `text='Frame : %{eif:n:d:3}' to get the zero-padded frame count (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64170163/10705720))
- use a monospace font (courrier new is common on Windows)
- the script was failing to load the font, use the full path instead but **without the drive** (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54923686/10705720)):

  - Do: `/Windows/Fonts/courbd.ttf`
  - Don't `C:/Windows/Fonts/courbd.ttf` nor use `\`

Comment: I'm unsure what's wrong. It's about using ffmpeg via batch file, so I guess the solutions to my issues can be either ffmpeg's arguments or additional batch scripts, if not both, and I hope people knowing better than me can help me find what can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the eif function.

Below is how it is used on the command line. You'll want to escape it for use in a batch file. `3` is the field width. For best results, use a fixed-width font.

```
text='Frame \: %{eif\:n\:d\:3}'
```

Comment: Indeed, that does the trick, thank you! I also noticed my script also failed to load the font file, fixed using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54923686/10705720). If I understand well, [eif aka expr_int_format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion) basically outputs an integer, `\:n` feeds eif with the current frame value (as in my initial script) and `\:d\:3` makes eif output a 3 **d**igits integer.